# python selenium unable to click on hidden element in dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python3 selenium.

I am trying to click on option 100 in dropdown here : https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/#
Please see attached image [image]

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import sys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % random.choice(proxies))
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/#')
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="skipValue1"]')))
except:
    sys.exit()
```

I tried many methods in class `Select` & `ActionChains` but no success as the element is hidden & doesn't get loaded without hovering. Also tried both `Firefox` & `Chrome` browsers , I think some Javascript execute might help but not sure how ?

Any help! highly aprreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you unhide the element ?

Comment: I did but it didn't worked : driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="downIndicator ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"]).click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution. You need ActionChains:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
hovermenu=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="current roundedMenu" ]')))
actions.move_to_element(hovermenu).perform()
WebDriverWait(driver , 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[(@class="menuItem") and (text()="100")]'))).click()
```

Please make sure to have these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```